# ListBox selection only one item in wpf xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I have a `ListBox` in my WPF application. That `ListBox` contain `Image` control, `TextBlock` etc. When user click on one item in `ListBox`, I want to select only that `Image` control. see the attached image. How can I do like this selection?
[image]

my code,

```
  <ListBox Name="mediaListBox" BorderThickness="0"  SelectionChanged="mediaListBox_SelectionChanged"  ItemsSource="{Binding ThumbnailItems}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" Background="Transparent" Drop="ImagePanel_Drop" AllowDrop="true">
            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ScrollContentPresenter}}}" >
                    </WrapPanel>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <StackPanel Width="120">
                            <Grid>
                                <Image Height="90" Source="{Binding Path=Thumbnail}" Margin="0,8,8,0" MouseLeftButtonDown="Image_MouseLeftButtonDown"/>
                                <Button Visibility="{Binding IsVisible,Converter={StaticResource booleanVisibilityConverter}, FallbackValue=Hidden,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Style="{DynamicResource CloseButton}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Command="{Binding ElementName=mediaListBox,Path=DataContext.RemoveGallaryItemCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem}"  Width="16" Height="16" Content="x"></Button>
                            </Grid>
                            <TextBlock TextWrapping="NoWrap" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" >
                                <TextBlock.ToolTip>
                                    <ToolTip Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=PlacementTarget, Converter={StaticResource trimmedVisibilityConverter}}">
                                        <ToolTip.Content>
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                                        </ToolTip.Content>
                                    </ToolTip>
                                </TextBlock.ToolTip>
                            </TextBlock>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>

                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

Currently,

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a custom `ControlTemplate` for the `ListBoxItem` container, e.g.:

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Border x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                                    SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                                          SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" 
                                          VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Green" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Green" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: Ok, that's good. But how can I set the border only for image control? not select all the items. Select border only for image control.

Comment: yes, I tried this. Border working perfectly, but it cover all items, I need border only single image, look like the attached images.

Comment: You should get a border around each item that you define in your ItemTemplate. Please post a screenshot of what you are currently seeing.

Comment: Updated, please check it.

Comment: There is a border around the second (selected) item, isn't this what you want?

Comment: Actually I want the border not cover the full items,  see the image which the border covered both image and title, i need to cover only image, not cover the tittle. Any idea for border only for image?

Comment: Then you should add a Border element to your ItemTemplate and use a DataTrigger that binds to the IsSelected property of the parent ListBoxItem container as I suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50323638/wpf-xaml-listbox-selected-item-border-color/50332364#50332364